# Ffmpeg stream from 2 pipes in Python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, udp, pipe

I want to create a UDP stream from 2 input pipes (video from an image pipe, and audio from multiple wav files or another pipe) and generate one combined output. Ideally this would be done using ffmpeg for python, and no command line.
All my tests failed.

I tried:

`ffmpeg.input('pipe:pipeout').output('udp://127.0.0.1:1234', r='30', ss='0').global_args('-re').run()`

but the framerate is too fast and also it gets the output "trailing options were found on the commandline" and generates no stream.

How can I generate the stream?